# Left, center and Right h1, h2 inline

Tags: html, css

I cannot align this three elements. I would like to make something like this

[image]

but I get this
[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <div id="controls" class="text-center">

            <h2 class="text-left">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-small"></i>
            </h2>

            <h1 class="fittext text-center"> 
                Sunday
            </h1> 

            <h2 class="text-right">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-small"></i>
            </h2>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS** (Sass)

```
#controls
    display: inline
    h1, h2
      display: inline-block
```

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: right? are you expecting us to do it for you? whats the problem

Comment: ok sorry, question updated with screenshots

Comment: change the width of center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#controls{
text-align:center
}
h1, h2{
display: inline-block}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pnBFY/1/)